# Rails: ActiveRecord association won't work when specifying foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, associations, rails-activerecord

I am trying to set up an ActiveRecord association.  Below are my two classes and I'm specifying the foreign_key option that I've read about here: [api.rubyonrails.foreignkey](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Options)

**School**

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :students, :foreign_key => :institutionid
     attr_accessible :name, :city, :state, :zipcode, :institutionid
end
```

**Student**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :school, :foreign_key => :institutionid
     attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :institutionid
end
```

**Database Schema**

dbo.school `{id:int, institutionid:int, name:nvarchar(255), city:nvarchar(255), state:nvarchar(2), zipcode:nvarchar(25),}`

dbo.student `{id:int, institutionid:int, firstname:nvarchar(255), lastname:nvarchar(255)}`

When trying to access the above with `<% debug @school.students %>` I get the following output on the page `--- []`

Can anyone help me find out what I'm doing wrong? Or provide some other ways of troubleshooting the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any data? Meaning a school with students. Also is there reason not to use :school_id as the foreign key, or at least :institution_id?

Comment: yes i can provide that schema, one second.  I was wondering if I provided the foreign_key wrong on both objects, but not sure.

Comment: Since you're getting an empty array instead of an error, I'd say it's making a query. I would check the log for the SQL. If it looks legit, I would paste it into your database browser and see what it returns.

Comment: @user198201, probably a silly question but where can i find the log with the sql query in it?

Comment: @user198201, ok this is the query being ran `SELECT [students].* FROM [students] WHERE students.institutionid=@1` Any idea whats with the @1 ? When substituting the @1 for my value 433 it works fine in sqlserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking for all of the students that have an institutionid of 433. However institutionid is not the primary key of School (and I wonder why not?). So when you say school.students, the query will use the value in 'id' not in 'institutionid'. I would try changing Student's association to:

```
belongs_to :school, :foreign_key => :institutionid, :primary_key => :institutionid
```

and change School to:

```
has_many :students, :foreign_key => :institutionid, :primary_key => :institutionid
```

Comment: This was exactly the issue. Thanks!